# What is the difference between pam_unix and pam_systemd?

Tags: systemd, pam

As I know, there are many pam modules

```
#ll /usr/lib64/security/ | grep pam | wc -l
57

#ll /usr/lib64/security/ | grep pam_unix.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 Apr 14 23:40 pam_unix_acct.so -> pam_unix.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 Apr 14 23:40 pam_unix_auth.so -> pam_unix.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 Apr 14 23:40 pam_unix_passwd.so -> pam_unix.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 Apr 14 23:40 pam_unix_session.so -> pam_unix.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  57688 Dec 13  2015 pam_unix.so

#ll /usr/lib64/security/ | grep pam_systemd.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 267840 Sep 18  2016 pam_systemd.so
```

but, what is the difference between `pam_unix` and `pam_systemd`?

#### For example: crond

when I mask `systemd-logind`, I find that: crond process ---->pam_systemd------>systemd-logind, but, what makes crond decide to call `pam_systemd` but not `pam_unix` ? what difference between `pam_unix` and `pam_systemd`?

```
crond[48269]: pam_systemd(crond:session): Failed to create session: Unit systemd-logind.service is masked.
```

Answer (score 3):

[PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) means Pluggable Authentication Module and is based on [RFC 86.0](http://www.opengroup.org/rfc/mirror-rfc/rfc86.0.txt).

[`pam_unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix) and [`pam_systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html) are two different modules with different roles. According to their respective man pages:

> [**pam_unix**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix) [is the m]odule for traditional password authentication
>
> [...]
>
> This is the standard Unix authentication module. It uses standard
>   calls from the system's libraries to retrieve and set account
>   information as well as authentication. Usually this is obtained from
>   the /etc/passwd and the /etc/shadow file as well if shadow is enabled.

and

> [**pam_systemd**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html) [r]egister[s] user sessions in the systemd login manager
>
> [...]
>
> pam_systemd registers user sessions with the systemd login manager
>   systemd-logind.service(8), and hence the systemd control group
>   hierarchy.