# What are the differences between `su target-user` and `login target-user` ?

Tags: login, su

What are the differences between

```
su target-user
```

and

```
login target-user
```

? The latter may need `sudo`.

They both seem to me to create a login session for `target-user`. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the relevant paragraph at the end of [the `login` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html) (in the “BUGS” section)?

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks. I am not sure why the newer version manpage (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1@@shadow-utils.html)  that I have read didn't mention that. No longer valid? Is the new i.e. shadow-utils version  more  or less accurate that the old version?

Answer (score 1):

> They both seem to me to create a login session for target-user.

In reality, they do not.  `su` does not create a login session.  It "switches user" to run a program under the aegis of a different user account, adding privileges (that account's privileges) to the totality of privileges available to the user of the *existing* login session that it is run in.

In fact, the `login` program does not create a login session *either*.  It expects the login session, with the process running `login` marked as the *session leader* process and a controlling terminal attached, to have been set up already by whatever invoked it.  `login target-user`, assuming the C shell's built-in `login` command that is effectively an `exec`, co-opts the *existing* already-set-up login session for another user account.  This of course entails risks that are well known by this point.

This is of course considering the kernel's concept of a *login session*, which involves a *session leader*, a *controlling terminal*, and *process groups*.  The systemd people have invented their own entirely application-mode concept of a login session, managed by `systemd-logind` in conjunction with PAM plug-ins.  The rules are slightly different here, in part because the systemd people botched them by conflating service stop at shutdown with session hangup (and still need to fix this).  But `su` does not create this type of login session either.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405780/5132
- [How does the (sd-pam) process get away with unprivileged `pam_session_close()`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396361/)
- [What is the difference between pam_unix and pam_systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372431/)
- [Which systemd service starts text console on the framebuffer device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194197/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016-06-01). *[Re: systemd kills background processes after user logs out](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394#221)*. Debian bug #825394.